# System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL after migrating from Silverlight 3 to 4

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

Following is the statement where I am getting the error :

```
var query = from c in objSearchedData.ToList() select c;
q = query;
```

Error:

> _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766
>   {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.}

I am using DBML and wcf service for the Silverlight 4. I have just migrated from Silverlight 3 the project. In old application its working fine. But after migration I am getting the error above.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when calling a method in my domain service from my Silverlight client.

I don't think this applies to you, but I added the `HasSideEffect` attribute to my method and it fixed it. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
[Query(HasSideEffects = true)]
public IQueryable<Entity1> GetEntitiesSafe(byte[] bytes)
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.